# Does Mozart use music theory, and if so, what type of music theory?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, composition, composers, mozart

I have heard various people argue that we are taking rules in music theory too seriously these days, often taking them as strict rules (such as the use of V-I cadences to end pieces), while earlier composers are more “free spirited”.

What formal techniques did Mozart use in his days? Or did he rely much on formalized techniques in composition?

Comment: He doesn't any more - been dead for a long time! Dare say finished decomposing, too...

Comment: What kind of strange feeling! You’d better inform yourself in wikipedia etc. instead of having feelings. I bet Mozarts’ head was more filled with music theory and musical basics at 4 years than the ordinary average of a 16 years old high school student of today.

Comment: There's an excellent question embedded in here about the history of theory and what Mozart would or would not have read or studied. However, as written, it lends itself to opinion-based answers. Please consider rewriting.

Comment: I do agree there is a history question in here that is very good, however the entire body of the question seems to fall into the pitfall of the assumption seen in this question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61479/can-music-theory-sabotage-creativity. Music theory and "free spirited" composition are orthogonal.  One does not take away from the other.

Comment: @Aaron good point. I just rewrote the question.

Comment: @Aaron since this question is rewritten to be less opinion based, can it be reopened?

Comment: I think you're headed in the right direction. IMO, the part about people taking theory too seriously is what sets up opinion-based answers. If it were me, I'd remove that part entirely and make this a pure history question. But consider opening a second question along the lines of asking for examples where composers specifically used or discarded accepted theory.

Answer (score 5):

Mozart has been musically educated by his father Leopold and was influenced by Johann Christian Bach and Joseph Haydn.

He was trained in studying counterpoint, harmony, chord theory.

*It is likely that Mozart studied Fux's work first under the influence of his father ...*

http://www.opus28.co.uk/Fux_Gradus.pdf

Fux: *Gradus ad Parnassum*.

Also see: Haydn - Mozart connection and J.Chr. Bach - Mozart Connection.

*The two composers knew each other, defended each other, and learned from each other in ways that shaped their musical output for much of their lives — despite a vast difference in age and temperament.*

*Perhaps it was the very differences between these two men of genius that drew them to each other. Whatever it was, they drew support and inspiration from one another in ways that profoundly affected their work.  If they had not met, neither would have been as productive, and their output far different.*

*In this hour, the story behind the deep friendship between Joseph Haydn and Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, and the great music it inspired.*

http://www.capradio.org/classical/connections/2014/03/08/connections-030814/

*Mozart's Counterpoint: Its Growth and Significance*

https://www.jstor.org/stable/727803

https://www.nytimes.com/1988/08/14/arts/music-what-haydn-taught-mozart.html

*Mozart’s lifelong admiration for Bach began during the family’s first trip to London,
1764-65, when Mozart was only eight years old. This trip marked the beginning of an
extraordinary relationship, documented in letters written by Wolfgang, Leopold and
Nannerl. Mozart met Bach at the height of the latter’s fame, when he was completely at
home in the active musical and social life of the metropolis. While in London, Mozart
enjoyed a close relationship with Bach, and apparently composed under his tutelage the Composer.*

https://www.biu.ac.il/HU/mu/min-ad/06-2/8_Bach-Mozart89-104.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The [basics of modern western music theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50725/when-was-music-theory-first-studied) probably originated with Pythagoras about 2,500 years ago. By Mozart's time music theory was already very well developed. How do you think he actually wrote down his music? He used the notation of music theory. It would probably be easier (and much quicker) to identify the music theory that Mozart *didn't* utilize.

The suggestion that composers like Mozart were “free spirited” and had little to do with music theory shows a lack of knowledge and understanding of both music theory and Mozart's music.

Comment: Ancient Greek music theory had very little to do with Common Practice Tonality. Common Practice theory is generally considered to have begun with Rameau's *Traite de l'Harmony" in 1722.

Comment: @ this would imply that all Baroque-music before Rameaus' *traité* was not common praxis?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli by definition, "common practice" refers to the harmonic system that arose in the 18th century.  So yes, Baroque music before Rameau did not employ the "common practice."  If you look at early Baroque music, there are certainly elements of it, but yet it is different.  Its harmonies often resemble those of the late Renaissance more strongly than those of the late Baroque.

Comment: @Aaron you’re mistaken. Rameau’s influence echoed in Mozart’s time either, but there were other earlier influences. Tonality isn’t a word defined in this era.

Comment: @RodrigoB.Furman It's true that tonality was in the process of being developed earlier and later, but it was Rameau's treatise that codified, in particular, the idea of chords being stacks of thirds and that inversions could be interpreted as variations on a root chord.

Comment: @Aaron, harmony these days was though differently. Even in Mozart's days, for example, you may find scores with minor keys notated in dorian key signature, as dorian mode was the reference for minor. There was a close link between harmony, melody, form and schema - and the stacking of thirds, well theorized by Rameau, was indeed comprehended, but still the harmony was secondary to melodic movement of individual voices or schemata patterns. I suggest you read both books by Robert Gjerdingen: Music in Galant Style and Child Composers in Old Conservatories.

Comment: @RodrigoB.Furman Thanks for the reference. Just know, I agree with you that during Mozart's time there was a continuing evolution from older practices and conceptions of musical form and such. I'm not arguing that composers based their work on Rameau. I'm saying that *theorists* based their work on Rameau -- that Rameau provided the necessary foundation for the theory now typically used to describe common practice-era music. And the larger point was simply that Pythagorean theory had little to do with Mozart.

Comment: @Aaron Fétis was the first theorist after Rameau to write about this, in 1840's, more than 100 years after Rameau's Traité publishing. Before 1850's, every music treatise was counterpoint-centred or "de natura sonoris", in metaphysical meaning. And, also, harmony is one of the tools necessary to describe common pratice period (1650-1900), along form and counterpoint. But CPP's also a concept now being debunked, as some of the "common practices" by many composers aren't so common after all (not fully explained by traditional harmony), as showed brilliantly by neoriemannian analists.